# OSX Sierra - How to Install PHP7 and leave 5.6 as default in Terminal

Tags: php, macos

short question - how to install php7.1 on OS X Sierra and keep 5.6 as default.
I only want to run php 7.1 in terminal using php7 - and when using php the original 5.6 should be used ...

thanx in advance
tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. I would install [PHPBrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew), since that allows you install as many PHP versions as you want without touching the system's PHP version.

I would also install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) as it's likely there will be dependencies you need to resolve with specific extensions.

Another option would be to install PHP7 via Homebrew and alias it to php7. Or you could compile it from source. However, if you plan on having one or more PHP versions readily available alongside the system version then PHPBrew is probably the most flexible option.

Comment: thank you matthew for your feedback and all the different ways you describe there! my problem is that i wanted to avoid to install all this apple xcode mess on my notebook just to run php7 in the end. what i found in addition were these binaries but it looks like if i install them 5.6 as default would be overwritten? https://php-osx.liip.ch

Comment: You really need Xcode installed to do any development at all  on OS X because so much relies on having a C compiler available. Trying to work around that is painful and not worth the bother.

Comment: is there a way to just install the xcode c-compiler without installing 4.5 GB? :) and sorry to bother you with my 'ideas'

Comment: There is the Xcode command line tools, which *may* be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: hi matthew - good idea! i'll give this a try. thank you :) tom

Comment: matthew - worked perfect! just 160mb instead of 4.5gb :))) thanx again

Comment: If it solved your problem then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install PHP 5.6:

```
brew install php56
```

Install PHP 7.0:

```
php70
```

Switch to php5.6 in terminal:

```
brew unlink php70
brew link php56
```

Switch to php7.0 in terminal:

```
brew unlink php56
brew link php70
```

Source: [Switching PHP version on mac with homebrew](https://fixes.co.za/php/switch-php-version-with-mac-homebrew/)

Comment: thank you surfer190 - perfekt solution in combination with matthews xcode command line tools :) have a good one - tom

Answer (score 0):

maybe someone other is searching for a very clean solution too - here is what finally worked for me perfectly. this is based on the hints and tips from matthew daly and surfer 190 - thanx again!

takes just 5 minutes - here we go ...

first install xcode command line tools (just 160mb instead 4.5gb):

```
xcode-select --install
```

then install homebrew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

short test if anything up to here is fine:

```
brew doctor
```

install php 7.1:

```
brew install php71
```

i found that some have problems with the above direct php install - this resolves these problems - and then try again the php install:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
```

make a symlink to the original php-binary that came with osx:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php5
```

here is the result - now php 7.1 is the default php version - and using php5 will use the old php-binary that came with your osx preinstalled:

```
php -v
php5 -v
```